# Java hibernate how to use select ... where id in ()

Tags: java, hibernate, select

I have Account class--account table mapping already.

Now I need use

> from account where account_id in (select account_id from anothertable where...)

I got an error saying

**org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: account is not mapped [from account where account_id in (select account_id from anothertable where...)]**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use **CLASS NAME**, not **TABLE NAME**. Thank you for your time anyway.